# Angular UI router - Check parent state?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, web, angular-ui-router

TLDR; Is there a function similar to `state.is()` to check for a state which has a lot of child states, from one of its child states?

This is my setup:

```
Parent 1
    Child 1.1
    Child 1.2
    Child 1.3

Parent 2
    Child 2.1
        Child 2.1.1
        Child 2.1.2
    Child 2.2
    Child 2.3
```

I want to hide a certain element on all the children and grandchildren of Parent 2. Currently I am using the ugly way of checking each and every state.

Comment: Can you detail your question. What do you mean by TDLR here. Parent and Child are similar to Div in HTML?

Comment: It's a state hierarchy built using `angular ui.router`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use $state.includes() do to a partial search for a state

Comment: Eureka! This is what I ended up using! Thanks!